# LNK 2019 while compiling main.c

Tags: c

I am just a beginner in C and Visual Studio and I have this weird error.
I declared a function in cipher.h and defined it in cipher.c (I have included cipher.h in cipher.c). I include cipher.h in main.c and used the function. But it gives me this error while compiling main.c:

```
unresolved external symbol test_encrypt referenced in function _main
```

### Here are the codes:

cipher.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void test_encrypt(char message[]);
```

cipher.c:

```
#include "cipher.h"

void test_encrypt(char message[])
{
    message[0] = '0';
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cipher.h"

int main(void)
{
    // open a text file and read the text into an array called buffer
    // the text is "54321"
    test_encrypt(buffer);
    printf(buffer);
}
```

Everything works fine if I remove the line that use test_encrypt function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a linker issue most probably because `cipher.c` is not compiled with your code. Make sure that you compile `cipher.c` together with `main.c`.

Comment: And the `buffer` variable is not defined, at least in your code example.

Comment: use: `cl main.c cipher.c`. Add compiler arguments like `-I` and so on as you already did. Show your compiler command next time in the question.

Comment: cl main.c cipher.c works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Think about the C compilation stages.

First C sources are built into objects. Those are compiled files which are like building blocks of your final executable. When you call `cipher` in your main, the compiler looks at the included headers and see if it finds anything that matches it. Since you have defined the function prototype, the compiler knows that such function exists somewhere, but it does not know where, at this stage.

The main.o object will have a reference to `cipher` declared as "external". After this stage of compilation, it's the linker job to be sure that the symbols you have are somewhere. From here it looks either in the other object files or in some libraries, and if it can't find it anywhere, it throws the error you are seeing.

What I can imagine it's happening here is that you didn't specify "cipher.c" to be part of you VS project, hence "cipher.o" is not being built, resulting in the error from the linker.